# Meteor error: Could not locate the bindings file

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have respond from meteor: "Error: Could not locate the bindings file." and then it shows places searched for file - in one of them file exist  - look attached picture [screen showing sought file exist in searched localisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10yFW.png) . 
I tried several remedy from this site but I'm bit confuse working with cmd. So, please explain to me like I'm 5 what and where I could change to make it work. 
I have to add meteor application originally was made on iOS and I'm on windows. Problems started when I'm trying to add package accounts-password and then run application.

Answer (score 0):

In the net are lots of advices what to do and I did everything I found but  none sad to do "meteor update" and only this works for me. So thumbs up, please.
reason was most likely: creation of the app on older version of the meteor. That worked fine most of the time but adding accounts-password course it couldn't find bcrypt. Simply "meteor update" solved problem.